# If the sides of a parallelogram are not equally long the diagonals are not perpendicular to each other?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I proof by contradiction that If the sides of a parallelogram are not equally long the diagonals are not perpendicular to each other?

Answer (score 0):

The diagonals of a parallelogram cut each other in half. If the diagonals are perpendicular, that means that relection along $AC$ swaps $B$ and $D$, which shows that $AB$ and $AD$ have equal length.